# Unit Testing of an API in Kotlin?

Tags: api, unit-testing, kotlin, junit

I am new to this unit testing, can somebody help me in writing a unit for an API that is used for logging. I don't know where to start and how to start writing tests for an API.

Comment: There are no test cases for a specific use case it totally depends on your business logic https://kotlinlang.org/docs/jvm-test-using-junit.html can help you

Answer (score 0):

**Reference:**

Alrigth, this article helps me to understand what we, developers, should test in unit tests. You can start with it: [unit test foundation](https://medium.com/rd-shipit/test-doubles-mocks-stubs-fakes-spies-e-dummies-a5cdafcd0daf)

**Code example:**

Now I'll share my code with you. It's an app to rating breweries near of your location.

RatingSearchAPIImp is a repository using a service to communicate with API and, this way, to get user's brewery ratings. Look:
[Repository to communicate with API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivMOj.png)

The method getRatings on repository returns this sealead class:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlGRr.png)

Now let's take a look on test class. The initialization of mocked variables.
[mocks and functions run before code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bonLL.png)

In this test. I do code http be 200(ok) and the body response also be an ok list of ratings.
With this scenario I verify if the result on repository is Success when API response is perfect.
[test method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aRxK.png)

**Conclusion:**

The point is: in unit testing with API you define service answers and verify if your repository method return the rigth answer.